# How to sort using column header as reference?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in VBA to sort a column using it's header name? Since the column may change regularly, I cannot reference the column number to sort it, I need to use the column header for sorting. For Example, I have *Order status* (column header) in Column C and I need to sort this *Order status* instead of mentioning it as *Column C*.

This is the code I have so far:

```
'Sort the "Order Status(Column C)" 
'Clear out any previous Sorts that may be leftover
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear

'range that includes all columns to sort
Set Rngsort = ws.UsedRange

'Columns with keys to sort
Set RngKey1 = ws.Range("C1")

'Perform the sort
With ws.Sort
    Rngsort.Sort Key1:=RngKey1, Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlSortColumns, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

Comment: Show your current code by which you sort by column number

Comment: I moved your code to the question, so please delete your comment. Anyhow, see my answer I already posted

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** after OP's showing his current code

you could use this helper sub:

```
Sub SortIt(rngToSort As Range, header As String)
    With rngToSort ' reference passed range to sort
        .Sort key1:=.Rows(1).Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole), _
              order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes ' sort it by its column whose header is the passed one
    End With
End Sub
```

that you can exploit in your current code as follows:

```
With ws ' reference your sheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear 'Clear out any referenced sheet previous "Sorts" that may be leftover
    SortIt .UsedRange, "status" 'Perform the sort on the referenced sheet used range
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst `.Find` I suspect is more efficient, and there is certainly less code, which is good, I was interested in having a play using `Application.Match` so wrote the following, which I would welcome feedback on...

I essentially try to match the `headerToFind` string in the header row of the `usedRange` and, if not found use error handling, otherwise sort.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Const headerToFind As String = "Header2"

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")       'change as appropriate

    Dim RngSort As Range
    Dim sortField As Long

    Set RngSort = ws.UsedRange
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear

    On Error GoTo Errhand

    sortField = Application.Match(headerToFind, RngSort.Rows(1), 0)

    Dim RngKey1 As Range

    Set RngKey1 = RngSort.Rows(1).Cells(sortField)

    With ws.Sort

        RngSort.Sort Key1:=RngKey1, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
                     OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
                     Orientation:=xlSortColumns, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With

Exit Sub

Errhand:

Select Case Err.Number

Case 13

    MsgBox "Header not found"

Case Else

    Debug.Print Err.Number & Err.Description

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it, basically change `Header:=xlYes` and then `key1:="HeaderName"`

Eg

```
ws.Range("A1:" & lColLet & lRow).Sort key1:="Area", order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 0):

General solution

```
range.Sort key1:="header1", _
order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:="header2", _
Order2:=xlAscending, _
Key3:="header3", _
Order3:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlYes
```